# Adding new column with static value to a select query result

Tags: php

I want to know what is the best approach if I want to perform select query to MySQL database and then add a new column to the result array which will be exported to a file at later time?

To clarify the process, assume the table have the following data:

```
id  name lastname     email 
1   john   doe    example@example.com
2   jane   doe    example2@example2.com
```

if I perform the following select query :

```
     $query = "SELECT * from table_name";
     $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
```

I get the previous result , and then I want to add a new column to it with static value for all the rows like the following:

**Important note:** I want to add the column to the returned result not to the database ,because this result is written into a file at a later time.

```
const_value  id  name lastname     email 
samevalue    1   john   doe    example@example.com
samevalue    2   jane   doe    example2@example2.com
```

currently I'm doing this using PHP:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
        {  
            array_unshift($row , 'samevalue'); 
        }
```

So is there an easy method of doing this in php or in MySQL during the query ?

Comment: It's nice to know of alternatives, but I'd like to add that your current way is also fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in the original query if that makes sense to your process like this

```
SELECT 'SameValue' as const_value, id, lastname, email from table_name;
```

If you really want to do it in PHP then something like this

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    $row['const_value'] = 'SameValue';

    . . . your other code
}
```

Or if you want to keep all the rows for later processing

```
$rows = [];
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))  
{  
    $row['const_value'] = 'SameValue';
    $rows[] = $row
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , the query return "Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception" ,  maybe you can't use the asterisk when defining a column name , is there a way to fix this or should i name all the columns  ? it is hard for a table with large number of columns if you know what i mean .

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '* from users' at line 1

Comment: $query = "SELECT 'SameValue' as const_value, * from users";

Comment: yeah it worked , but for some important reason can you please suggest a modification to mysql statement to put the static part at the beginning

Comment: Yes, you will have to do `SELECT 'SameValue' as const_value, col1, col2 FROM table`

Comment: Or `SELECT 'SameValue' as const_value, table.* FROM table`